# How to install Mysql Server In Ubuntu Server that has no Internet Connection

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I Tried Downloading the deb package and installing it since the machine has no internet i downloaded the dependencies required. However, it started a chain of dependencies required for each of the dependency.

Can someone let me know how we can achieve this ?.

Comment: Since you have no Internet Connection, what i could image is just copy all of the necessary files to the machine via other medias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer for this question tells you how to install mysql in **ubuntu 11.04**.
For **Ubuntu 12.04 precise 64 bit**, find below the required packages and the installation order.

```
sudo dpkg -i libnet-daemon-perl_0.43-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libplrpc-perl_0.2020-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdbi-perl_1.622-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient18_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdbd-mysql-perl_4.021-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libterm-readkey-perl_2.30-4build3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libhtml-template-perl_2.9-2_all.deb
```

*Note : libterm-readykey-perl is the additional package that you need to install here.*

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for the response. Finally after lot of trial was able to download all the required pacakage and install them in orderly fashion. So thought I shall share the following for future reference although someone might have already tried.

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/libnet-daemon-perl/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/libplrpc-perl/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/libdbi-perl/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mysql-common/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/libmysqlclient16/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/libdbd-mysql-perl/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mysql-client-core-5.1/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mysql-client-5.1/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mysql-server-core-5.1/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/mysql-server-5.1/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/libhtml-template-perl/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/mysql-server/download
```

Finally Installed them by following the order:

```
sudo dpkg -i libnet-daemon-perl_0.43-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libplrpc-perl_0.2020-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient16_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdbd-mysql-perl_4.016-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client-core-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-core-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-server_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i  libhtml-template-perl_2.9-2_all.deb
```